# Yii2 delete ActiveRecord error message sometimes array, sometimes not?

Tags: php, activerecord, error-handling, yii2, delete-row

I have this in Controller, generated with **giiant** (I assume it's correct):

```
public function actionDelete($id) {
    try {
        $this->findModel($id)->delete();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $msg = (isset($e->errorInfo[2])) ? $e->errorInfo[2] : $e->getMessage();
        \Yii::$app->getSession()->addFlash('deleteError', $msg);
        return $this->redirect(Url::previous());
    }

    $isPivot = strstr('$id', ',');
    if ($isPivot == true) {
        return $this->redirect(Url::previous());
    } elseif (isset(\Yii::$app->session['__crudReturnUrl']) && \Yii::$app->session['__crudReturnUrl'] != '/') {
        Url::remember(null);
        $url = \Yii::$app->session['__crudReturnUrl'];
        \Yii::$app->session['__crudReturnUrl'] = null;

        return $this->redirect($url);
    } else {
        return $this->redirect(['index']);
    }
}
```

Now my problem is, that it throws sometimes `$msg` as array and I have no clue why.

View/index:

```
if (\Yii::$app->session->getFlash('deleteError') !== null) {
    echo Alert::widget([
        'options' => ['class' => 'alert-danger'],
        'body' => \Yii::$app->session->getFlash('deleteError'),
    ])
;}
```

The error message:

> PHP Notice – yii\base\ErrorException
>
> Array to string conversion

I have no clue why is it sometimes array and sometimes not. All controllers are the same, but for some Models it's working, for some not. I can implement a workaround that `if is_array then ...[0] otherwise ...` but I feel it's not the right way to solve the problem. How can a Model change the data type of this error message? Can you please point me to the right direction? Many thanks.

Comment: Can you show us an example of an error you get?

Comment: can you show what does the `findModel()` function look like or is it the default generated function by GII

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you're actually never using model validation here, so it has nothing to do with model. Second, `$msg` is probably OK, the problem is how you're using [`getFlash()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-session#getFlash()-detail). This method *may* return array, this is expected and documented:

> The flash message or an array of messages if addFlash was used.

You should either iterate trough `getFlash()` result to get actual message as string, or use widget which will handle this and generate multiple alerts from `getFlash()` result.

You may also use [`setFlash()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-session#setFlash()-detail) instead of `addFlash()`. But I would not recommend this - it is easy override some previous flashes and you should not blindly assume that  `getFlash()` result will be a string.

Comment: It's still not really OK. There is no real solution which implements addFlash. It doesn't make any sense one simple delete error message in an array... I don't get the picture. Maybe this is not really OK: `$msg = (isset($e->errorInfo[2])) ? $e->errorInfo[2] : $e->getMessage();`

Comment: I've changed all Delete actions to use setflash instead of addflash, this is the only way I could make it work.